# Using file descriptor with here document

Tags: bash, heredoc

I want to open here document into a file descriptor with number 3. Which later I copy into standard input of cat command. But this doesn't work. See below

```
#!/bin/bash

cat 3<<222889 
I am reading
a string into 
file descriptor 3 which is copied to standrad input
222889
0<&3
```

Comment: Why do you want do do this? You want to read in a multi line string?

Comment: Also what is the use case/intention for/with this?  Doesn't make any sense at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place both redirectors on the same line:

```
cat 3<<222889 0<&3
I am reading
a string into 
file descriptor 3 which is copied to standrad input
222889
```

Then `cat` just outputs everything in the here document, plain.